SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON React Custom Hook useFetch
I am trying to implement a custom hook useFetch which receives url and options as parameters. Upon testing the hook, I am getting the above error and I am not sure why.
The codes I've written
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useFetch({ url, options = {} }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setPending(true);
      const res = await fetch(url, options);
      const apiData = await res.json();
      //   console.log(data);
      if (apiData) {
        setData(apiData);
        setPending(false);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
      setPending(false);
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);
  return [data, pending, error];
}

index.js
import useFetch from "./useFetch";

export default function TestUseFetch() {
  const [data, pending, error] = useFetch("https://dummyjson.com/products", {});
  if (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
  if (pending) {
    return <h2>Data loading..</h2>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <h2>Error occured. ${error}</h2>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="data">
      <h1>Use Fetch Hook</h1>
      <div>
        {data &&
          data.products.map((item) => {
            return <div>{item.title}</div>;
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

The url (api) path is working fine on browser. But I'm getting the mentioned error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON" when trying to fetch data using the Fetch API. What am I missing? What does this error mean?

Your api call is returning an HTML page instead of the JSON you expected.  It's probably an html-formatted error page.  Look at its contents before trying to parse it as json.

What is the final options value? E.g. POST request to given URL will return 404 HTML error page

fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products").then(r=>r.text()).then(t=>alert(t)); seems to work fine, no traces of HTML in the response.

@Justinas It is GET request. And the api works fine in Vanilla JS.
